# Id of a view at a coordinate

Tags: android, view, coordinate

At a given pixel location, there is a view. I have the coordinates of the pixel. How to find the id of a view at a given coordinate ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are inside of `ViewGroup`:

```
int count = viewgroup.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   View view = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
   if (view.getX() == theX && view.getY() == theY)
          return view.getId()
}
```

**EDIT (kcoppock):** within the for loop, I'd do something like this:

```
View view = viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
if(!view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) continue;
int[] location = {0, 0};
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int right = location[0] + view.getWidth();
int bottom = location[1] + view.getHeight();
Rect bounds = new Rect(location[0], location[1], right, bottom);
if(bounds.contains(coordinatesX, coordinatesY)) return view.getId();
```

Comment: That's close, but only going to work if he clicks the EXACT pixel of the upper left corner of the View. I'll edit in a suggestion.

Comment: exactly.  You'll also want to ensure that getChildAt() returns a View that is visible (getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)

Comment: Edited that in as well. Also fixed my edit as I'd written `getLocationInWindow` rather than `getLocationOnScreen`. I suppose it depends on implementation, but I think typically screen coordinates would be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

1. Walk your view hierarchy to find child views (i.e. those with no sub-views) that are Visible.
2. use View.getLocationOnScreen() on your views to retrieve their location (the top/left window coordinate)
3. use getMeasuredWidth() / getMeasuredHeight() to get the view width and height
4. see if your pixel coordinate falls within this rectangle